# Capped sum that needs to stop before the limit

Tags: c#

I have been trying to make a program that you input a number and i keeps asking for numbers untill their sum has reached the number and displays how many numbers it took. the problem i'm facing is that if the last number makes it over the input number it still counts it while it should stop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sumLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;`

        while (sum < sumLimit)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      
            sum += number;
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum + " " + count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Have an intermediate step that checks the addition and `break` out if it is over `sumLimit`

Comment: well then u do not need the last read line

Comment: @spzvtbg That's likely there to keep the program from exiting when debugging.

Comment: You can just output `count - 1` in the WriteLine at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option to fix it, depending on your expected result you can let the count start at -1 or 0:

```
    int sumLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int sum = 0;
    int count = -1;
    int number = 0;
    
    while (sum + number < sumLimit)
    {      
        sum += number;
        count++;
        number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum + " " + count);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It will display 0 -1 for negative `sumLimit`, but I am not sure are there any restrictions about that, upvote anyway.

Comment: I didn't think about negative numbers indeed.